# Google appengine can store java object POJO

Tags: java, google-app-engine

Can App Engine Store information like the ObjectOutputStream?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, GAE can store blobs of data. Use [Blobs](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/datastore/Blob) for data up to 1Mb, and the [Blobstore](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/blobstore/overview) for larger objects.

Answer (score 0):

GAE does support Blob data. But there are some size limitations. Here is the [API documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/datastore/Blob)

But other option is to make POJO's extended from com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Entity are serializable and , GAE can do store information. If you are looking for some documentation or information around it, check this [out](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/entities). More information on extending an entity can be looked up [here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/datastore/Entity).

Answer (score 0):

```
      FileService fileService = FileServiceFactory.getFileService();

      // Create a new Blob file with mime-type "text/plain"
      AppEngineFile file = fileService.createNewBlobFile("text/plain");

      // Open a channel to write to it
      boolean lock = true;
      FileWriteChannel writeChannel = fileService.openWriteChannel(file, lock);




      MyObject obj = new MyObject();
      obj.name="testing now";
      ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(Channels.newOutputStream(writeChannel));
      oos.writeObject(obj);
      oos.flush();
      oos.close();
      // Now finalize
      writeChannel.closeFinally();

      // Later, read from the file using the file API
      FileReadChannel readChannel = fileService.openReadChannel(file, false);
      ObjectInputStream ooi = new ObjectInputStream(Channels.newInputStream(readChannel));
      resp.setContentType("text/plain");
      try {
        resp.getWriter().print(ooi.readObject().toString());
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Here is code for save POJO to blobstore . MyObject  need implement Serializable interface .